# Obtaining control group mean after running Matching::Match command

Tags: r, propensity-score-matching

After running `Match` to perform propensity score matching, I want to identify the control mean so I can plot the mean value for the control group and the mean + estimate for the treatment group side-by-side.

I'm at a loss as to how I can extract this from the output of `Match` though. My thinking is I can use the index.control value to identify the control group and then estimate the mean and SE from there, but i'm so far not having any luck with this approach.

I'd welcome any ideas!

This code reproduces a simple PSM:

```
library(carData)
library(tidyverse)
library(Matching)

matching_df <- Mroz %>% 
  mutate(wc = case_when(wc == "yes" ~ "TRUE", 
                        wc == "no" ~ "FALSE")) %>% 
  drop_na(k5, k618, age, wc, hc, lfp)

matching_df$wc <- as.logical(matching_df$wc)

ps1 <- glm(wc ~ k5 + k618 + age + hc, 
           family = binomial, data = matching_df)

pscore <- ps1$fitted.values
matching_df <- cbind(matching_df, pscore)

Y <- matching_df$lfp
Tr <- as.logical(matching_df$wc)
  
psm1 <- Matching::Match(
  Y = Y, 
  Tr = Tr, 
  X = pscore, 
  estimand = "ATT", 
  M = 1, 
  replace = TRUE, 
  caliper = 0.05, 
  version = "fast")

summary(psm1)

Estimate...  0.17479 
SE.........  0.044963 
T-stat.....  3.8873 
p.val......  0.00010135 

Original number of observations..............  753 
Original number of treated obs...............  212 
Matched number of observations...............  207 
Matched number of observations  (unweighted).  1074 

Caliper (SDs)........................................   0.05 
Number of obs dropped by 'exact' or 'caliper'  5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is to run:

```
mean(as.numeric(Y)[psm1$index.control])

[1] 1.519553
```